# Are there op amps in Logicworks?

Tags: logicworks

I'm trying to design a circuit in Logicworks that uses an op amp, but I can't find any op amps. Is there an op amp in Logicworks? If there isn't one, then what can function like one?

Comment: What are you trying to do? maybe that can be simulated without the op-amp.

Answer (score 5):

Opamps are linear (analog) devices.  Logicworks simulates only digital characteristics, so does not support opamps or any form of equivalent circuit.